# How to install python version 3.5.6 into ubuntu/ Linux?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I need to install **python version 3.5.6**. What are the requirements to install python 3.5.6.

> python 3.6 is already installed on my local machine

**What I have tried?**

1. I looked into [Python downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Downloaded tarball for **python3.5.6**.
2. Installed it by using following set of commands

   ```
   wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.6/Python-3.5.6.tar.xz
   tar -xf Python-3.5.6.tar.xz
   cd Python-3.5.6
   sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev libsqlite3-dev build-essential 
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
3. After installation when I run `python3 -V` it shows `python 3.6`.

**Expected behaviour**

`python3 -V` command should show `python3.5.6`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can run all Python 3.5 programs with Python 3.6 just fine (aside from possible binary dependencies). Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I have specific installation requirements that depends on python 3.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python3.5` might show `3.5.6`, depending on where and how things are on your PATH.

Either way, instead of manually compiling and installing Python (especially as you're side-stepping your package manager (`apt`) here which may cause trouble down the line), look into [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). After installation, approximately:

```sh
$ pyenv install 3.5.6
$ pyenv local 3.5.6
$ python
```

and you're ready to roll.

Comment: I have compiled and installed source files already. But did not work

Comment: Thank you! So much this worked for me. Is it good for switching python versions. For an instance, switching from 3.5.6 to 3.6 and vice versa?.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling it or removing the package all together from your computer. Afterwards try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.5
```

or you could try:

```
$ sudo aptitude reinstall python2.7
```

Best of luck.